# Jquery Client-Side Form Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just found out that using Jquery for form submission also means I need to use Jquery for client-side validation as well. I have done some research and found the reportValidity() function which does everything I need it to do, but I am not clear on what the code does.

My question is on the `[0]` in `$("#loginemail")[0]`

```js
$("#loginbutton").click(function() {
  if ($("#loginemail")[0].reportValidity()) {
    alert("login email is valid");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="loginemail" autofocus required><br>
<input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="loginemail" required><br>
<input type="button" value="Log In" id="loginbutton"></br>
```

I read that when Jquery is told to use the selector, say for an id, it will find all instances of that id and make an array. The [#] is to clarify to Jquery which id to act upon. You can see that I have two email fields, each with the same id of 'loginemail'.

When the index is set to [0], filling in the first email box and clicking Log In results in a successful alert.

However, when the index is set to [1], this means Jquery should be acting on the 2nd email box. When I fill in the 2nd email box correctly, the alert does not show. Why is this?

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 1):

An ID **must** be *unique* in a document. Use [a markup valitor](https://validator.nu/) to fix errors in your HTML.

The selectors API optimises searching for ID selectors by assuming your document is not invalid (and stopping after it finds a single match).

(It doesn't perform that optimisation for an ID attribute selector, but you should fix the HTML instead of hacking around the problem. Use a class instead.)

Comment: Yes, the 2nd duplicate ID is only there because I wanted to test out if reportValidity would select the duplicate. But if the selector only stops after finding the first matching ID (as it should, since ID should be unique), what is the point of having the [0] there? I took it off and the code stopped working.

Comment: The `[0]` retrieves the Element from the jQuery object. You can use `get(0)` instead if you prefer. In either case the code works (for the first input only, obviously) so your issue is unclear.

Comment: (a) because there is a difference between the jQuery object and the zero-or-more DOM element objects it wraps and you need to distinguish between them and (b) because if it returns one thing or an array of things depending on how many things there were it would mean you would have to test to see if it was an array or not each time you used it in a situation where it wasn't certain to return exactly 1 thing.

Comment: I see. But then in the line above:
$("#loginbutton").click(function()

It does not require the [0], AKA it does not read$("#loginbutton")[0].click(function().

If I do add the [0], the code stops working. How do I know when to use or not use the [#]?

Comment: @yosimba2000 — You should know if you are using a jQuery or DOM API (largely because of where it is documented)